Updating and extracting coordinates from moved grid using QGIS
I am trying to extract updated coordinates from a grid after moving it.
I am using QGIS 3.32.1-Lima on Windows 10.
My objective is to plan a 20m x 20m survey on a map and then extract the resulting corner points of the repositioned grid to use on the ground in the field.
This is my workflow so far:

Vector > Research Tools > Create Grid
Layer > Toggle Editing
Edit > Select > Select All Features
Edit > Edit Geometry > Move Feature(s)
Edit > Edit Geometry > Rotate Feature(s)

If I then export the edited layer to a csv file, the coordinates have not changed.
When I right-click and Open Attribute Table I see the coordinates of the left, top, right, bottom are still the original points and not the moved ones. I have seen vaguely similar help requests that say to use the Field Calculator to get the updated coordinates but find the advice then becomes too complicated for me to follow.
I have a low technical limit and seek either suggestions for a different, possibly simpler workflow or an explanation of the final steps to achieve what I'm trying to do.

https://www.northrivergeographic.com/qgis-adding-x-y-coordinate-field-calculator/

If you export the layer as .csv without specifying anything, it will only export the non geometry fields of your layer which contains id,left,top,right,bottom from the original grid, but not the actual coordinates.
If you want the X Y coordinates to be exported, choose Geometry AS_XY in the export menu.

Your .csv will include X & Y columns with the actual point coordinates

Selecting GEOMETRY as AS_XY did not extract the new coordinates. It produced an identical result as leaving GEOMETRY as .  I followed the suggestion by lambertj to look at the method at https://www.northrivergeographic.com/qgis-adding-x-y-coordinate-field-calculator/ and this worked.
I cannot see how I flag lambertj suggestion as the correct answer in Stack Exchange

That's strange, I did get the correct coordinates, and even though the bottom, top coordinates will not change as they are  static properties, exporting the Geometry fields should export the actual (modified) coordinates . You cannot flag lambertj's suggestion as an answer as it is a comment.
